# What's going to happen to my booked AirBerlin flight now that they've gone bankrupt?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, cancellations

AirBerlin have just declared that they're going bankrupt. I have tickets booked with them for a Berlin-Chicago-Munich itinerary for the end of September.

I understand the German government has provided AB with a loan so they can continue to operate for now; however, unlike with Alitalia, no one seems to be providing any commitment to the length of operations of this company. The question is how do I know for sure my flights are going to operate, without risking a last-minute cancellation from them which will force me to buy expensive last minute tickets? Is there a way to receive money-back on my non-refundable tickets at this point?

Comment: The answer is: you just don't know it.

Comment: If another company quickly buys the remaining assets from AirBerlin, they might choose to honor the tickets. Else you'll probably just have to get in line with all the others that AirBerlin owes money to, hoping to get (some of) your money back. Personally I would guess that the end of september is close enough that your journey will be operated with the loan, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't know until you know...:(  Most likely, they will continue to operate for several months.  You may be rebooked on another carrier or other carriers, particularly OneWorld will honor the tickets.

Comment: Are you more worried about loosing your money or about not being able to make the trip (on time). I mean, in case you booked a cruise for example, though they don't usually start from Chicago, your bigger problem might be to miss your ship than loosing money on the air tickets.

Comment: Anecdotal experience: I lost my money when SpainAir went bankrupt. IF you paid with Visa or something that allows you to cancel the payment withing a period of time, try to cancel it. That is the only way people got their money back, when the SpainAir thing happened

Comment: Important note: Air Berlin has filed for bankruptcy _protection_, not filed for bankruptcy. That's a very different thing. For example, United, Delta and American Airlines have all been in bankruptcy protection (known as "Chapter 11" in the US) for two years or more this century; they're all still operating.

Comment: In the UK, credit card providers have liability for purchases between £100 and £30,000 made with the card, and have to refund your money if the actual supplier breaches the contract. If you paid with a credit card (not a debit or charge card) it might be worth checking if Germany has similar laws.

Comment: In USA, the consumer is only liable for $50 in case of fraud.  Visa has voluntarily made it zero.  But I'm not sure this counts as fraud.

Comment: Election is on September 24. After that, politicians will remember they distrust corporations/don’t believe in supporting individual corporations (depending on their political inclination), so the loan most likely won’t be extended. But until then, you should be safe relying on the government.

Comment: Crucial missing information a) **Did you book directly with them, or through a travel agent?** (if in UK, ATOL bond would apply) b) **What country do you live in? (determines which consumer laws applies)** c) **Did you pay with a credit card, debit card, check or cash?** (affects your rights with the merchant in a dispute)

Comment: @DavidRicherby A Chapter 11 filing is still bankruptcy. It's just a reorganization bankruptcy rather than a liquidation. Also, I'm not quite sure what the point of mentioning the duration of the reorganization plan is. Each of those airlines have only filed bankruptcy once ever (DL and UA following the huge drop-off in air travel after 9/11 and the .com bust recession, while AA struggled along until the '08/'09 financial crisis put them out of their misery.) Air Canada also filed in between UA and DL.

Comment: @reirab The relevance of the duration is that the asker only needs their airline to keep flying for a couple of months; United shows that an airline in bankruptcy protection can keep going for three years.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah, reorgs can take a long time, but that doesn't really have any meaning to passengers. What does have meaning is whether the bankruptcy is pursued as a reorg or a liquidation. Liquidation looks more likely in Air Berlin's case. Alitalia's case doesn't look much better. Best case for each of them is probably being purchased in whole by another airline, in which case operations might continue as usual. The loan should keep Air Berlin going for the duration needed by the OP, though.

Comment: Not to freak out the OP, but does this have any immigration implications. I'm guessing they'll enter in a visa waiver, but if the future of the airline is in doubt, does that have an impact on entry (since exit is in doubt)?

Answer (score 67):

Called AirBerlin. They're saying that at the moment they are expecting all flights within the next 3 months to operate normally and that I should check back in one week to get an update about possible refunds and cancellation policies.

Comment: There was no need to call - it all is stated on [their website](https://flights.airberlin.com/de-DE/airberlin). But this does not answer your own question - can you trust this information?

Comment: @Neusser can you trust official company statements? Yes. Can the company screw everyone by doing the exact opposite? Yes. But for the stack, an official statement is a reputable source.

Comment: @Mindwin: In typical bankruptcy procedures, the company statements don't count for much once a court-appointed executive takes over operations. The statement can be a valid representation of the intent of Air Berlin, but that still doesn't make it trustworthy.

Comment: As this is a large company and an official statement placed on their website I am fairly sure this has been going through their law department and the appointed executive before being posted.

Comment: The question you need to ask is whether you can trust the word of a company on the verge of full bankruptcy. Of course you can't

Comment: There's a difference between *trustworthy* and *reliable*.

Comment: You are allowed to accept your own answer (two days after you post it), and doing so would help others in future.

Answer (score 31):

Unfortunately, I would not give a dime on anything which a call center agent tells you now or in a week from now. On the other hand, legally, you don't have too many options unless you did not just purchase a ticket from their website but it would be part of a packaged holiday. In case of packaged holidays there is a mandatory insurance against bankruptcy at least in Germany.

Your problem is: AirBerlin may operate your flight or they may not. You will know once you've arrived at your final destination. Given their personnel situation (which is unlikely to improve now and has been bad already) it will be enough if they cannot find a crew on the day you plan to travel.

On the other hand, you don't have any chance right now IMHO to have your tickets refunded and book with a different airline. The only bet on the future you could make is to try and buy a refundable ticket with another airline now (maybe for a day later) and give it back if AirBerlin will fly.

Last chance: Check the credit card you possibly used to pay for the flight. Some cards (especially and "Silver" and "Gold" cards come with all kinds of insurances. Not sure if bankruptcy of an airline is one of them, but it may be worth checking.)

But please also note that all those insurances would if at all only make sure you either get your money back, but you will still not travel then. At least not at the insurance's expenses. Only if there would be such an insurance and you made it to your destination but your flight back home doesn't take place the insurance would pay for suitable means to get you back home, but that would be all. They will never pay the difference to a more expensive ticket if you haven't started the trip yet.

Comment: In the US I would be able to chargeback the charge as services not delivered. I guess they don't work the same in Germany.

Comment: @Joshua It would be absolutely the same in Germany. The only problem will be that you will end up with a claim against a company which filed bankruptcy. So you will face trouble to cash in that claim. Who would pay in the US in that case?

Comment: @TorstenS: With a credit card, chargebacks don't leave *you* with a claim. The CC company will be paying Air Berlin with some delay, so they'll have to figure out how to settle the final payments, but that's not your problem.

Comment: @MSalters So you are saying you'll turn to your credit card company and ask them to cancel the payment you have done already? Is it still possible / that simple? I remember in the old days (20 years back) I once called Amex and just told them I contradict a charge they made and they immediately credited it back to my account. But I am 99% sure it doesn't work that way any more. Does it in the US? That would render the whole purpose of credit card payments (the seller is guarateed that you irreversibly paid) void.

Comment: @TorstenS: I've done it in Europe, fairly recently. And no, I don't have an idea where you got the idea from that sellers benefit from credit cards. CC's are quite bad for sellers. Payments are irreversible after a year or so has passed.

Comment: @MSalters You can't chargeback a company which has no money left. If the OP gets their money back in such a case, it most probably means their CC company or bank covered the loss for them.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Or (and that's one of the ways in which CC's are bad for sellers) the CC company hasn't paid the seller yet, while they've already taken the money from the buyer. In case of a chargeback, the buyer just gets his money back. The only reason why sellers put up with this is because there are very few CC companies, it's effectively a duopoly between Visa and Mastercard.

Comment: @MSalters I seriously doubt that CC companies are allowed to keep the income of their sellers for a whole year. That would mean the airlines needed their annual revenue worth of cash just to keep buying fuel and paying salaries while the transactions from ticket sales clear up.

Comment: @MSalters I had heard one month; but I did encounter a fast food business that offered a 7.25% cash discount so ...

Comment: Modern credit card processing for retail stores pays *daily*, as in a direct deposit shows up every day. Might be more or less often for airlines but it's definitely not months or a year.

Comment: Just because CC companies deposit the cash daily, doesn't mean they don't reserve the right to claw it back from future payments, for longer than one day.

Answer (score 9):

[German news reports](http://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/airberlin-155.html) say that a government loan will secure the next three months of operation. The intention is to avoid disruption of (return) travel during the summer holidays; quite a lot of Germans are currently abroad with AirBerlin tickets.

So I'd be confident about the next couple of weeks; things might get tricky if those €150M don't last the full three months.

Comment: Today's radio report also suggested that in the worst case scenario, AB customers would be rebooked to different airlines.

Comment: @Robus There are potentially two problems with that: 1. Who will pay for that and 2. are there sufficient capacities with other airlines. Also I guess they will make a difference between people who are on the far end of their trip and need to get home and those who did not yet leave.

Comment: @TorstenS I'm just relaying what I heard on my morning commute, personally I'd ditch the AB ticket and buy one with a different airline if I needed to attend anything important ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This does not quite answer the question, but hopefully is helpful enough to warrant posting.

Assuming you become confident the flights will not be honored (probably due to the an announcement by the company, or after the flight date).

If you paid for goods and services, and did not receive said goods or services, you can request a chargeback with the bank you used to pay (assuming you didn't pay in cash I guess). BPay may also result in you being unable to process a chargeback.

For more detail about cahrgebacks, check [this link](https://www.commbank.com.au/personal/accounts/managing-your-accounts/dispute-a-transaction.html), or better still, contact the bank you paid with.

Note that companies that have gone bankrupt are [still valid targets of a chargeback](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-577680.html). Depending on the severity of the situation, a chargeback may be unsuccesful if they have no money available.

Disclaimer, I am not a banker or a lawyer or familiar with chargebacks or flights in Germany. Talk to your bank.

Comment: Bad idea. The liquidator will claim back the money (to which the bankrupt company is entitled). In the end, all you did is incur additional costs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you could do at this point, other than rely on what the company has said...

However, in the future, it's a great idea to buy travel insurance for your trips.  This would at least cover some of the expenses, should something untoward happen on your trip.   And, I'm sure, the airline going bankrupt and not flying would be covered...(or at least you might be able to claim any delta's in costs)

E.g. We went on a cruise vacation with non-refundable Iceland Air tickets -- on the way home, Iceland Air decided that they were going to have a 1 day mechanics strike so we were 'stuck' in Iceland for that day...we were automatically rebooked for the next day (well, after stopping by an airline counter)...however, due to the insurance, we got back most of the money we incurred by spending another night in the hotel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just as I assumed, Air Berlin have cancelled most of their North American routes effective October 1st, which means that my flight back is not going to be operated by Air Berlin.

I already called my credit card company, and they promised that I'll be issued a refund if the flight didn't operate. However, they said I'd probably have to wait until the flight itself to claim this (unless I get a written statement). My insurance does not cover cancellations in cases of airlines' financial troubles.

Does anyone have any information about the eminent Lufthansa takeover? Do you think they will honor the flight back (United has a direct ORD-MUC flight)? And in case they didn't, under European Flight Cancellations regulations, would I be able to receive compensation if the flight is cancelled under two weeks before its time?

Comment: If the airline is bankrupt then it is unlikely to be able to pay out EC 261/2004 compensation even if it is legally required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In a case where AB is unable to provide the service before the operational cover runs out (estimate is three months but honestly this is unrealistic), you will be honoured the flight on another (most probably EW) operated flight (that will take over the route).

Worst case you get your money back after the bundled slot that affect your flight is taken over and AB no longer operate.

Comment: Can you back this up with references? Given the other part of your original answer (which I edited out), I'm suspicious that these are guesses/opinions too.

Comment: well, you deleted hard facts...not sure I understand why?

Comment: and yes, in fact I can... not publicly though.